# Is it possible to loop over an httplib.HTTPResponse's data?

Tags: python, streaming, httplib

I'm trying to develop a very simple proof-of-concept to retrieve and process data in a streaming manner. The server I'm requesting from will send data in chunks, which is good, but I'm having issues using `httplib` to iterate through the chunks.

Here's what I'm trying:
    import httplib

```
def getData(src):
    d = src.read(1024)
    while d and len(d) > 0:
        yield d
        d = src.read(1024)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    con = httplib.HTTPSConnection('example.com', port='8443', cert_file='...', key_file='...')
    con.putrequest('GET', '/path/to/resource')
    response = con.getresponse()

    for s in getData(response):
        print s
        raw_input() # Just to give me a moment to examine each packet
```

Pretty simple. Just open an HTTPS connection to server, request a resource, and grab the result, 1024 bytes at a time. I'm definitely making the HTTPS connection successfully, so that's not a problem at all.

However, what I'm finding is that the call to `src.read(1024)` returns the same thing every time. It only ever returns the first 1024 bytes of the response, apparently never keeping track of a cursor within the file.

So how am I supposed to receive 1024 bytes at a time? The documentation on `read()` is pretty sparse. I've thought about using urllib or urllib2, but neither seems to be able to make an HTTPS connection.

HTTPS is required, and I am working in a rather restricted corporate environment where packages like [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) are a bit tough to get my hands on. If possible, I'd like to find a solution within Python's standard lib.

## // Big Old Fat Edit

Turns out in my original code I had simply forgot to update the `d` variable. I initialized it with a read outside the `yield` loop and never changed it in the loop. Once I added it back in there it worked perfectly.

So, in short, I'm just a big idiot.

Comment: with urllib2, have you seen HTTPSHandler?  `opener = urllib2.OpenerDirector()
opener.add_handler(urllib2.HTTPSHandler())`

Comment: You need a con.send() after putrequest() to get anything back. Your sample iterator works for me on HTTPConnection objects.

Comment: @tdelaney I'm getting data back without the `con.send()`, and it is the correct data, but I'm only getting the first 1024 bits. I tried adding `con.send("")` after the `con.putrequest()` and I'm still getting the same result.

Comment: @KenB - it worked for me on an http connection when using con.request(...) but I am not setup to do an https connection. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Is your con.putrequest() actually working? Doing a request with that method requires you to also call a bunch of other methods as you can see in the official httplib documentation:

http://docs.python.org/2/library/httplib.html

> As an alternative to using the request() method described above, you
>   can also send your request step by step, by using the four functions
>   below.

```
putrequest()
putheader()
endheaders()
send()
```

Is there any reason why you're not using the default HTTPConnection.request() function?

Here's a working version for me, using request() instead:

```
import httlplib

def getData(src, chunk_size=1024):
    d = src.read(chunk_size)
    while d:
        yield d
        d = src.read(chunk_size)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    con = httplib.HTTPSConnection('google.com')
    con.request('GET', '/')
    response = con.getresponse()

    for s in getData(response, 8):
        print s
        raw_input() # Just to give me a moment to examine each packet
```

Comment: Yeah, I did use that set of functions. I didn't bother adding them in the example, but I was putting a mess of headers and such.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the seek command to move the cursor along with your read.

This is my attempt at the problem.  I apologize if I made it less pythonic in process.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
     con = httplib.HTTPSConnection('example.com', port='8443', cert_file='...', key_file='...')
    con.putrequest('GET', '/path/to/resource')
    response = con.getresponse()
    c=0
    while True:
        response.seek(c*1024,0)
        data =d.read(1024)
        c+=1
        if len(data)==0:
            break
        print data
        raw_input()
```

I hope it is at least helpful.

Comment: This doesn't work. From what I'm reading in [the httplib docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/httplib.html#httplib.HTTPResponse), `HTTPResponse` doesn't have a `.seek()` method. I've also confirmed it by experiment; `response` throws an `AttributeError`.