# Wait until all data is gathered

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a script I put together its not too long, but I find when I run it I only get so many sets of data back. 
The data dictionary I put together manually and I am passing each server and its api key into the api to get back only a few results. (Some nodes are missing) I am then writing those results out to a db.

My question is, how can I make this script wait until it gets the first set of data back before proceeding to get the next set?

```
import httplib
import json
import pyodbc

boxes = {'server01': 'xxxx'}
for node, api in boxes.items():
    headers = {'Accept': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Server apikey=' + api}
    conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection(node)
    conn.request('GET', '/api/v1/devices?limit=10000&search_type=any', headers=headers)
    item = conn.getresponse()
    resp_str = item.read().decode('utf-8')
    resp_Data = json.loads(resp_str)

    for data in resp_Data:
        cnxn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=xxx0001\SQLEXPRESS;DATABASE=TestDB")
        cursor = cnxn.cursor()
        query = ("insert into TableTest(node, is, name, id, ip)" "values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")
        cursor.execute(query, (node), data["is"], data["name"], data["id"], data["ip"])
        cnxn.commit()
        cnxn.close()
```

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Look at the `multithreading` module and the `start` and `join` methods.

Comment: huh? I think they want the opposite of that. They want all data, so `requests` should block until all data has been retrieved. Serialization is the opposite of concurrency (see also: [Is it possible to loop over an httplib.HTTPResponse's data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17452485/is-it-possible-to-loop-over-an-httplib-httpresponses-data))

Comment: correct, I am trying to get data from each of my servers in the list.

Comment: so the question is why is your server not returning everything in the response body you want after you `.read()` the HTTPResponse?

Comment: I went through each one independently and they are returning, I am thinking some are coming back faster, so it skips over some of them. I have close to 25 of them.